# Event not triggering for runtime controls in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Created a directive using AngularJS. The directive displays a runtime (dynamic) controls but it is not triggering an event from controller. Can any one help me.

Note: used compile in directive too.

The plnkr link is given below.

```
module.controller('controllerOne', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


    $scope.AddClickButton = function () {
        alert("Button Clicked");
    };


}]);

module.directive('directiveOne', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        scope: {

            data: '='
        },

        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            var btnhtml = '<button type="button" ng-click="AddClickButton()">Click Me</button>';
            var temp = $compile(btnhtml)($scope);

            $element.append(temp);

        }
    };
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="form1" >

    <directive-one data="dataOne"></directive-one>

</form>
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/iz6Buf?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing `AddClickButton` method reference to directive using `&`(expression binding) as directive has been using isolated scope. So it don't have any idea about parent scope directly.

**Markup**

```
<form name="form1" >

<directive-one data="dataOne" click-action="AddClickButton()"></directive-one>
```

And then call that method from directive using that `clickAction` isoalted scope prop.

**Directive**

```
module.directive('directiveOne', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',

    scope: {
      data: '=',
      clickAction: '&'
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var btnhtml = '<button type="button" ng-click="clickAction()">Click Me</button>';
      var temp = $compile(btnhtml)($scope);
      $element.append(temp);
    }
  };
}]);
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pWKnizMnLoLNOt6GcYEQ?p=preview)

Comment: Additionally I have a question. I am generating html tags dynamically with ng-click event. So do I need to mention all the action names in the directory. My idea is having directory as a common obj and controller has many methods, so when I generate html contents , just I need to mention the method/function name. is there any way to achieve ? for an example: - I have 3 buttons and 3 buttons click event calls different methods, so do I need to mention all the three buttons action names inside scope ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this version http://plnkr.co/edit/9QCpAQUhOKZ3NtU1rfhY

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.AddClickButton = function() {
         alert($scope.text);
      }
    }
```

and remove the function from the controller